What is the reason behind Sidney's statement about lacking alibis?
Sidney seizes the telephone from his assistant Sally, with Joe Robard
waiting on the other line:

Sidney (to Sally): Watch me run a 50-yard dash with my legs cut off.

Subsequently, Sidney engages in a conversation over the phone:

Sidney: Sidney: Hey, Joe. Joe, it's Sidney. How do you like this?
I'm running outta alibis. Oh, no. No, no. I asked J.J. to withhold
the item until he could give you a fine, fat paragraph.

What is the reason behind Sidney's statement about lacking alibis?

Sidney is making a joke to Joe about the fact that he's been hard to reach.
Obviously we, the audience, know that Sid has been intentionally putting Joe off and telling his secretary to make up excuses about why Sidney isn't available to speak because he doesn't want to speak to him, since he's got nothing to report, but Sidney is pretending that his alibis have been real, but that Joe might think by the sheer difficulty in reaching him, that they're fake.
Now he's at the crunch point where Sidney actually needs to speak to Joe to get him to pay for another week of PR work (despite having achieved no visible results), he makes a quip to his client about how they always seem to keep missing each other.
You could reword it as

"I'm going to have to stop pretending not to be able to take your calls, ha ha, no, but seriously..."

